# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No index used in query/prepared statement'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-insert-id, sql

When I run the following code, I get the error saying

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'mysqli_sql_exception' with message
>   'No index used in query/prepared
>   statement'

```
$mysql = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database');
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("DB error: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

    $get_emp_list = $mysql->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM calc");
    if(!$get_emp_list){
        echo "prepare failed\n";
        echo "error: ", $mysql->error, "\n";
        return;
    }
    $get_emp_list->execute();
    $get_emp_list->bind_result($id, $emp_list);
```

And this is the able schema --

```
--
-- Table structure for table `calc`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `calc` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `yr` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `mnth` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `paidleave` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `balanceleave` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `unpaidleave` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `basesalary` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `deductions` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `tds` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `pf` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `finalsalary` int(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this bug-report : [**`#35450`** mysqli extension reports too many warnings](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35450&edit=1)

Quoting a few sentences of a note :

> Mysqli extension throws too many
> warnings. 
> For example, "SELECT *
> FROM table" results in a warning:
> "Warning: mysqli::query(): No index
> used in query/prepared statement
> SELECT * FROM table ..."

And, quoting another note, which seems interesting :

> Use `mysqli_report()` to disable that.

Comment: Hmmm... I dont think thats deprecated, as I am using it very well.. mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean "doesn't work", but "shouldn't be used anymore, and might be removed one day or another"

Comment: Right, but what I have is not a warning, it is a Fatal error. I would WANT to know about Fatal Errors.

Comment: It shouldn't have been deprecated (appears it was by accident): https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55329

Comment: Yes, it is still a valid command in PHP7, with no deprecation message in the docs:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php

Answer (score 35):

The fatal error is not in MySQL; the missing index notification is a relatively low-severity warning.

The *fatal* error is in your PHP code, because of the following three conditions:

- mysqli reports a *lot* of warnings, even for relatively harmless conditions.
- You're throwing `mysqli_sql_exception` for all errors *and* warnings due to your `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` line.
- Your PHP code is not catching that exception (i.e. it's not in a `try{}`  block with an appropriate `catch(){}` block), and uncaught exceptions are fatal.

You can't do much about the first one, as mentioned in the other answer. So, you can fix it either by changing your `mysqli_report(...)` setting to `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` or `MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF`, or indeed anything other than `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL`.

(edit: w3d's comment below gives a good explanation why, and suggests you could use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)` as a good alternative)

For best practices, and in combination with this, you should fix it properly by using `try{}` and `catch(){}` appropriately within your code.

Comment: It's often low-severity but should not be neglected: the message states that the mysql server has to perform a full table scan, i.e. has to check on every record wether it belongs into the result set or not. In case of big DB an additional index to the searched columns could help.

Comment: Specifically, to remove these particular warnings, you need to remove the `MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX` flag from the `report_mode` property. This flag "Reports if no index or bad index was used in a query". So, use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)` as opposed to mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)` before executing your query.

Answer (score 12):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL ^ MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
```

Turns off "Report if no index or bad index was used in a query" yet keeps other reporting on.

Answer (score 2):

the message "**No index used in query/prepared statement**" not is about your code PHP it's about the design of your table, simply **ADD a index to your table**.

really the best is turn ON the error/warnings in DEVELOP:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

but turn OFF in production:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix it is to make your table column 'name' in MySQL an index.

```
ALTER TABLE `calc` ADD INDEX ( `name` ) ;
```

Comment: This is not enough if you have a small table. In that case MySQL/MariaDB will implicitly disable indexes in the table, and combine that with mysqli throwing if no indexes are used, you have a nice when-stars-align mess :) "Works in prod, does not work in staging/dev".