# PHP MySQL prepared statement: Execute dies, returns neither true or false

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

In this block, $stmt returns not false as expects, $bind is true, but when I get to $stmt->execute(), it exits, and returns neither true nor false. The only time I can get false out of it, is if I use some variable in the argument for execute per it's documentation, but I've never used an argument in an execute call, and I can't find an example of anyone else using one except in procedural prepared statements. I don't know if I'm missing something. Anyone have any ideas?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ... FROM `table` WHERE `tid` = ?");

if ($stmt !== FALSE) {
    echo 'Statement was true.';
    $bind = $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->tid);
    echo 'after bind';
    if ($bind)
        echo 'bind was good ';
    else
        echo 'bind was bad';
    $exec = $stmt->execute();
    if ($exec)
        echo 'exec was good';
    else
        echo 'exec was bad';
    echo 'after execute';
    // etc.
} else {
 // rest of code
}
```

@tntu's accepted answer and following comments got me on the right track for solving this problem. 
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580039/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-mysqli-sql-exception-with-message-no-index-us

MySQL can do a lot of error reporting, and I had set mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL) set earlier in the stack and in the function in question in order to figure out some other problems. 
At any rate, setting mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF) enabled the execute to run as intended, and not bog php down with warnings, and errors.

Comment: Are you sure that you have read the documentation and examples here: http://bg2.php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.prepare.php ?

Comment: Are you saying that the script never prints "exec was good" or "exec was bad"?

Comment: Yeah, because it would die on the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bind = $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->tid);
```

**s** stands for string

Change it to **i** and it should work.

Also see about doing some error management. `mysqli_erro`, `mysqli_errno`

Something like this:

```
if ($mysqli->errno) { logging("ERRO: ".$mysqli->error . "( " . $mysqli->errno . " )"); }
```

Comment: It did not. The problem persists.

Comment: Stupid question but are you sure you are actually connected to MySQL? There is error handling dedicated for connection errors.

Comment: Add this at the top of your code: ini_set("log_errors", 1); ini_set("error_log", __DIR__ . "errors.log");

Comment: Yeah, I check the connection on entering each function. It's redundant, and less efficient, but I've had the issue before. I think prepare would also pass false to me, if I wasn't connected.

Comment: [18-Oct-2012 08:56:28] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT ... FROM `table` WHERE `tid` = ?' in /home/www/htdocs/include/Audit.class.php:94
Then it gave me a stack trace.

Comment: This lead me to here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580039/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-mysqli-sql-exception-with-message-no-index-us Which fixed the issue. Thanks for helping me sniff it out @tntu

Comment: When you have a problem and something does not work make sure you do error handling and capture so you can see what is going on.