# No index used in query/prepared statement, when there is an index issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, error-handling

I am trying to perform a query and am getting the following error..

```
7Error: No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT `id`, `category_id`, `topic_id`, `post_creator`, `post_content`, `post_date` FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?
```

I originally had this line of code for it...

```
if($stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?")) {
```

So I tried changing it to the following to give it an index.

```
if($stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT `id`, `category_id`, `topic_id`, `post_creator`, `post_content`, `post_date` FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?")) {
```

Why would this error be occuring? I have php error reporting on.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

However, even when I comment it out, the error still occurs and it kills my code. Anyone know why this error is coming up and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29170597/5146041):

> mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL ^ MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
>
> Turns off "Report if no index or bad index was used in a query" yet
>   keeps other reporting on.

By using 'E_ALL', you are enabling the reporting of this error/warning.

Comment: When I do this I get this error..`7Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` for `$driver = new mysqli_driver();
 $driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL^MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX;`

Comment: There is a pretty thorough answer to the 'out of sync' issue at http://stackoverflow.com/a/614741/5146041